# Why do I get the following error: Could not parse YAML header: did not find expected key "source" (line ,,,,

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, pandoc, citations

I am using RStudio for writing a document in R markdown to produce a word output file. I am including references in the form

```
---
references:
- id: thisreport
  author: someone
   title: 'thatstudy with a long title'
  publisher:  Some Agency
  type: report
  issued:
     year: 2016
     month: 12
---
```

It worked, than I tried if I could simply change the output format into pdf, but got errors. After changing the code back, I obtained my word document again, but got the above mentioned error message and no references are included in my document. It seems as if my experiment changed some global settings because I even cannot reproduce my former results although I took code from a backup file of which I know that it produced correct references.

Sorry therefore for not including a MWE as reproducibility is exactly what I am wondering about.
Please excuse my for the apparently stupid question but I can't find my error. 
And please account in your answer for my complete lack of knowledge of YAML and pandoc aside of what is needed to create a simple markdown document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your YAML is incorrect, `title` (maybe because you aligned the `:` after it with the one from the key above it), is indented one space too much:

This is the corrected header:

```
---
references:
- id: thisreport
  author: someone
  title: 'thatstudy with a long title'

  publisher:  Some Agency
  type: report
  issued:
     year: 2016
     month: 12
---
```

maybe you should start using revision control, with that it is often easy to see if something else has changed (inadvertedly, the cat stepped on the space bar) since things last worked.

Comment: Thanks! A double error of mine: I did not post the blanks precisely in my question, but you were still right that it was about the blanks which made my code not working. I was not aware of their importance by simply following the R Markdown examples.